# bash script echo always print the same space

Tags: linux, bash, printf, echo

I have a simple question. it's a bit hard to explain but I will do my best. I have multiple scripts that prints numbers, for example temperature and memory usage. these numbers can be 4 numbers (1000 MB) or less (500 MB), it needs to echo ( 500 MB). I know how to use the same space by making it 0500 MB, but thats really ugly.
You can probably do this with printf, but i have no idea how.

73nismit

Comment: `printf` is probably the way to go, but if you show some piece of your code we can guess better.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%7s" "500 MB"
```

will add a leading space to make the string occupy 7 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "#%4i#\n" 500
```

gives
    # 500#

you should look at the section 'Field and printing modifiers' in the [reference manual](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf)

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same for all printf implementations.

```
printf <FORMAT> <ARGUMENTS...>
```

You neded sth. like

```
printf "%7s\n" "500MB"
```

Have a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210225090311/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) for more examples: